# Query Open MapQuest API with Java HttpURLConnection gives no result

Tags: java, json, httpurlconnection, mapquest

I have written this code to access the Open MapQuest API from a Java program (APPKEY left out intentionally.. ):

```
public class OpenMapQuestAPITest {

  private final static String APPKEY="...";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String address="Germany, Hannover, Am Hohen Ufer 3A";
    URL url=new URL("http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search.php?key="+
        APPKEY+"&format=json&q="+address.replace(' ','+'));
    System.out.println("Query: "+url.toString());
    HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    try (BufferedReader in=
         new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {
      String inputLine;
      while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    System.out.println("Response: "+response.toString());
  }

}
```

I get this (key left out intentionally, line break added):

```
Query: http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search.php?↵
       key=...&format=json&q=Germany,+Hannover,+Am+Hohen+Ufer+3A
Response Code : 200
Response: []
```

Issuing exactly the same query from e.g. Chrome gives the correct response:

```
[{"place_id":"1528890","licence":"Data \u00a9 OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http:\/\/www.openstreetmap.org\/copyright",
  "osm_type":"node","osm_id":"322834134",
  "boundingbox":["52.3729826","52.3729826","9.7304606","9.7304606"],
  "lat":"52.3729826","lon":"9.7304606",
  "display_name":"3a, Am Hohen Ufer, Mitte, Hannover, Region Hannover, Niedersachsen, 30159, Deutschland",
  "class":"place","type":"house","importance":0.511}]
```

Why does `MapQuest` not return these data when I ask through `Java`? Is there some character escaping I am not aware of? Do I need to set some special user agent? Am I querying the connection object in a wrong way? After all, the service returns OK (HTTP status code 200), so it seems feel not too bad about my request.

Why doesn't it answer?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time these problems relate to url encoding.

**1. Try url encoding first.**

```
String address="Germany, Hannover, Am Hohen Ufer 3A";
URL url=new URL("http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search.php?key="+
    APPKEY+"&format=json&q="+address.replace(' ','+'));
```

Try:

```
URLEncoder.encode(address.replace(' ','+'), "UTF-8"));
```

**2.** You can go for **org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient** api. It has a class PostMethod (org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod), with which you can add parameters to it. (rather HttpUrlConnection) 
Like

```
HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
PostMethod pm =  new PostMethod(url);
// add parameters to it.
pm.addParameter("format","json");
hc.executeMethod(pm);
```